# Reverse osmosis draining

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens

How long before a new whirlpool reverse osmosis fills the tank and stops draining? I installed the brand new system this afternoon and after 4 hours it is still draining. Does that mean the tank is still filling or is there a problem?
Model is WHAROS5

Comment: Depends on the model and how much it uses to process, as well as tank size, and water pressure.

Comment: Be aware that RO systems drain more water than what gets captured as the filtered water. If you are using the filtered water regularly then there will be draining regularly as well.

Comment: From this site http://www.allianceforwaterefficiency.org/RO_Discharge_Introduction.aspx?terms=alternate+water+source there is this quote: "Depending on the model, most RO filter systems will discharge 4 to 20 gallons (15.1 L to 75.7 L) of backwash water for every gallon of filtered water it produces."

Answer (score 1):

That model can produce [18.4 gallons](https://www.whirlpoolwatersolutions.com/wp-content/manuals/WHER25/Reverse%20Osmosis%20System.pdf) of purified water per 24hrs or about 1.3 hours per gallon. So in seven hours, a 5 gallon tank should be filled. There may be other factors that affect this. If it is still running after 10 hours, you've certainly got a problem. Note that every time you use the filtered water, there will be additional draining.